# Sum of number of perfect matchings and a constant constuction

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, perfect-matchings, bipartite-graphs, permanent

Suppose we have two bipartite graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ with perfect matching count $P_1$ and $P_2$ respectively then their disjoint union gives a bipartite graph with perfect matching $P_1P_2$.

> Is there a graph construction from $G_1$ to get a bipartite graph with perfect matching count $P_1+1$ in polynomial time without knowing $P_1$?